# Facing issue while querying json data in Oracle db

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have table created with constraint to check is JSON;

structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE d_jobs (
    ID varchar2(500),
    jobs varchar2(4000)
    constraint ensure_json1 check (jobs is JSON)
 );
```

And `jobs` column will contains value as : `[{"jobid":"x","status":"done"},{"jobid":"y","status":"done"}]`

When I query:

```sql
select j.jobs.status from d_jobs j;
```

The output is: `["done","done"]`

But I want the output : `["done"]` --according to list position

I tried to query :

```sql
select j.jobs[0] from d_jobs j;  -- not sure if the given syntax is correct
```

```
Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 107 Column: 22
```

Can any help here? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select json_value(jobs, '$[0].status') status0 from d_jobs;
```

This gives you the value of the `status` attribute for the first element in the array, that is:

```
| STATUS0 |
| :------ |
| done    |
```